# Asking to stay reporting to same manager

Tags: team, manager

I work for a large international corporation with a variety of teams that work on different projects.

Generally employees are rotated onto different projects to gain more insight into the wider organisation, access new skills etc.

My current manager is great and I would really like to remain on a team that reports to them as I have a lot of respect for them and enjoy working for them. Is it inappropriate to ask to be rotated to a team that still reports to the same person?

Comment: This seems company-specific, though I doubt any harm could come from asking.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything wrong to ask for rotation preferences. The worst case scenario would be that the management just says no. Although, I am not sure if your corporate culture if there is such taboo to make such request, though.

Perhaps it might be worthwhile to ask around if there is such precedence request similar to this first?